# Why can't doInbackground method have empty body?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-asynctask

I have a class that extends `AsyncTask`. I pass in a list of cholesterol monitors and create the fragment in `onPostExecute`. However, `doInbackground` cannot be an empty method and `onPostExecute` also doesn't override correctly?

```
private class CholesterolFragment extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>, Void, Void>`{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>... arrayLists) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor> result){
            cholesterol_monitor= result;
            monitorListFragment = MonitorListFragment.newInstance(cholesterol_monitor);
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_monitor_layout, monitorListFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

In my onCreate I pass in the cholesterol monitor list:

```
monitor_list= this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("monitorList");

cholesterol_monitor = (ArrayList<CholesterolMonitor>) monitor_list;
CholesterolFragment cholesterolFragment= new CholesterolFragment();
cholesterolFragment.execute(cholesterol_monitor);
```

Comment: Why are you using AsyncTask if your doInBackground is going to be empty?

Comment: I need to get the Intent before passing it into the fragment. It keeps returning null reference pointer so I thought that it might have created the fragment before getting the intent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point in having an async task with an empty doInBackground, at that point you aren't doing anything asynchronously.  You may as well just do it directly on the main thread.

But the answer is that doInBackground returns a value.  So the body can just be return null; but it needs that return.